# How to modify configuration file from command line?

Tags: command-line, configuration, automation

For example, I often need to login to a new virtual machine just to open "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" and set "PasswordAuthentication" option to "no".

In this way, I can not automate this process.

How to solve similar tasks by doing the modification from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sudo sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication no/'
>   /etc/ssh/ssh_config